# log4Net - logger only using root appender, not other appender

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

```
<log4net>
    <logger name="LogManager2" additivity="false">
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LogManager2" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LogManager1" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogManager1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="logs\log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="_yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="LogManager2" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="logs\Logs2" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="_yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

when I am trying to use logger for logmanager2,

```
ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogManager2));
```

it is supposed to write log to logs2 file but logger is using root log file and logging data to logs file.I have tried all answers available regarding this topic,but nothing worked for me
can anyone explain me the problem?

Comment: how are you resolving the logger LogManager2? I mean, the exact code, case and all.

Comment: I have edited code. @A.Chiesa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require a Logger, you can pass a type or a string.

When you pass a type, Log4net searches for a logger with a name equal to the name of the class, including the namespace.

So, you should either call:

```
ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("LogManager2");
```

or rename the logger as `YourNamespace.LogManager2`. As this:

```
<logger name="LogManagerNamespace.LogManager2" additivity="false">
```

Comment: didnt work for me.. :(
I have two services and want to log info of two services in separate files. thts why i added two appenders but log is getting logged only root appender file.

Comment: I'm not following you. You have two services. And this is fine. You have two loggers, with two different appenders, and this is fine. Everything is going on root, because you call to GetLogger cannot resolve a logger for your LogManager2 type. You have to rename the logger, or call GetLogger with a string. I'm pretty sure this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this and I don't like the XML config so this is what I wrote (works from multiple different DLL's and creates a different log for each):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

using log4net;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Layout;

// ReSharper disable once CheckNamespace
namespace EasiPos.EasiLog
{
    public class Log
    {
        private static ILog _log;
        public static void Initialise(string logName, string logFile)
        {
            var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.CreateRepository(logName);

            var patternLayout = new PatternLayout {ConversionPattern = "%date %-5level - %message%newline%exception"};
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

            var rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender
            {
                AppendToFile = true,
                Name = logName,
                File = logFile,
                Layout = patternLayout,
                MaxSizeRollBackups = 10,
                RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date,
                StaticLogFileName = true
            };
            rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();

            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(rollingFileAppender);
            hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.All;
            hierarchy.Configured = true;

            _log = LogManager.GetLogger(logName, logName);

        }

        public static void Info(string message)
        {
            _log.Info(message);
        }

        public static void Debug(string message)
        {
            _log.Debug(message);
        }

        public static void Error(string message)
        {
            _log.Error(message);
        }

        public static void Error(Exception exception)
        {
            _log.Error(exception.Message, exception);
        }

        public static void Error(string message, Exception exception)
        {
            _log.Error(message, exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Initialise it like this:

```
using static EasiPos.EasiLog.Log;

Initialise("EasiKDS", @"TRACE\EasiKDS.exe.log");
```